# converting a method into a member functor object which calls the method leads to a crash

Tags: c++

I have the following method in a class:

```
bool temp_cmp(size_t l, size_t r) const {
    return memcmp(get_next_temp_record(l), get_next_temp_record(r), page_size) < 0;
}
```

But I need it as a functor object so I rewrote it like this:

```
struct temp_cmp_functor {
    const sorter& _s;
    temp_cmp_functor(sorter& s) : _s(s) {
        std::cout << "ADDR: " << &_s << std::endl;
    }

    bool operator()(size_t l, size_t r) const {
        std::cout << "ADDR AT CALL: " << &_s << std::endl;
        return memcmp(_s.get_next_temp_record(l), _s.get_next_temp_record(r), page_size) < 0;
    }
};
temp_cmp_functor temp_cmp{*this};
```

And now later on when I call it like `temp_cmp(idx1, idx2)` I get a crash in a sanitized build - with ASAN (the function `get_next_temp_record` accesses some fields of the class which are of type `std::vector` but I don't think that should be relevant).

Any idea why this change might be problematic? I'm printing the addresses of the object and they match in the constructor of the functor and when the `operator()` is called - I see no reason for this not to work... To me the 2 ways should be identical... What am I missing?

Here is the ASAN output:

```
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1061:34: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of   type 'const struct value_type'
../../demos/ip_demo.cc:185:33: runtime error: member access within null pointer of type 'const struct   value_type'
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==3862==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000020 (pc 0x00000047a8b4 bp   0x7ffe9e0042c0 sp 0x7ffe9e0042a0 T0)
==3862==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
==3862==Hint: address points to the zero page.
    #0 0x47a8b3 in std::__uniq_ptr_impl<char, seastar::free_deleter>::_M_ptr() const /usr/include/c++/  9/bits/unique_ptr.h:154
    #1 0x465ac5 in std::unique_ptr<char [], seastar::free_deleter>::get() const /usr/include/c++/9/ bits/unique_ptr.h:612
    #2 0x46635d in std::unique_ptr<char [], seastar::free_deleter>::operator[](unsigned long) const (/  home/onqtam/seastar/build/debug/demos/ip_demo+0x46635d)
    #3 0x45b146 in sorter::get_next_temp_record(unsigned long) const (/home/onqtam/seastar/build/   debug/demos/ip_demo+0x45b146)
    #4 0x45b3fe in sorter::temp_cmp_functor::operator()(unsigned long, unsigned long) const (/home/ onqtam/seastar/build/debug/demos/ip_demo+0x45b3fe)
    #5 0x420298 in operator() ../../demos/ip_demo.cc:421
```

Comment: Looks like you have lifetime management issues, your unique pointer appears to be empty when you access it.

Comment: @Mat but nothing else in the code has changed - all the vectors with unique pointers stay the same - I'm just switching from calling a const method to calling a const ```operator()``` of a member functor object at a single place...

Comment: `temp_cmp_functor` hold a reference to a `sorter` - that doesn't keep the sorter alive. If whatever `*this` was when you created your functor dies, using the functor has undefined behavior. That's all I can say with the code you posted.

Comment: @Mat this is all in the ```sorter``` class itself (and thus the ```{*this}``` for initializing the functor - all in private scope) - only 1 is being created in the program and the call to ```temp_cmp()``` happens within another method of the ```sorter``` class...

Comment: Try creating a minimal example which reproduces the problem. The information in the question isn't enough. What you described shouldn't happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the whole class was getting copied somewhere, and then the functor's reference to the outer class was pointing to the old location ==> memory corruption.